# Show Loading Image when TreeView Node is clicked in WPF

Tags: wpf

The question is we have a WPF application, which has Tree View. On the click of node Report gets generated which has no time interval (I mean no clue how much time it will take). So I am planning to show a Loading.gif file on the window till the report is generated.

How can I make the image (.gif) visible while the main window process to show the report and after showing the report I need to hide the image.

Do you have any other alternate method to do so.

Appreciate your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of Extended WPF Toolkit's [`BusyIndicator`](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=BusyIndicator).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sample of how to make async multi-threaded treeview -> http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/ThreadedWPFExplorer.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The general technique for this is:

1) Create an `IsBusy` property in the view model for your window; make sure it raises `PropertyChanged` when it changes.

2) In the code executed when the item is clicked, use a `BackgroundWorker` to run the long-running task.

3) Before calling `BackgroundWorker.DoWork()`, set `IsBusy` to true.  In the event handler called when the `BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted` is raised, set `IsBusy` to false.

4) In the `DataTemplate` for the window, add a `Style` with a `DataTrigger` bound to `IsBusy`, and use that to control the visibility of the image.

Note that you may be able to move `IsBusy` (and the long-running task and the `BackgroundWorker`) to the item view model instead of the window view model, and add a "Loading" animation to the `DataTemplate` for the *item*.

If you do this, the user can start multiple items loading simultaneously, and the entire application doesn't lock up just because one item in the `TreeView` got clicked on.  (Of course, you have to deal with any multithreading issues involved in generating multiple reports simultaneously).